# Comparation two objects in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have just started to learn Kotlin. I have two objects and I need to compare them. I only want list of cars with changed name (I want to do update garage object in database with new value when it's changed)

Object one:

```
{
    "name": "Tom's garage"
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": „Volkswagen”,
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": „1”,
                    „name”: „Golf”
                },
                {
                    "id": „2”,
                    „name”: „Tiguan”
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": „Audi”,
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": „3”,
                    „name”: „A3”
                },
                {
                    "id": „4”,
                    „name”: „A4”
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Object two:

```
{
    "name": "Tom's garage"
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": „Volkswagen”,
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": „1”,
                    „name”: „Golf”
                },
            ]
        },
       {
            "name": „Audi”,
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": „3”,
                    „name”: „A5””
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So in output I want only list of cars with changed name (Audi A3 to Audi A5) in the garage.

```
[
       {
            "name": „Audi”,
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": „3”,
                    „name”: „A5””
                },
            ]
        }
]
```

That's what I wrote, but I am not happy with my code. Can you suggest me better kotlin solution?

```
    fun findDiff(current: Garage, updated: Garage): List<Car> {
        val carsMap = current.brands.map {
                brand -> brand.name to brand.cars.map { car -> car.id to car }.toMap()
        }.toMap()

        val output = arrayListOf<Car>()

        for (brand in updated.brands) {
            for (car in brand.cars) {
                currentSettingsMap[brand.name]?.get(car.id)?.
                let { currentCar ->
                    if (currentCar.name != car.name) {
                        output.add(car)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return output
    }
```

Model:

```
class Garage(
    val name: String
    val brands: List<Brand> = emptyList()
)

class Brand(
    val name: String,
    val cars: List<Car> = emptyList()
)

class Car(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

It's learning example, does not have to make any sense.

Comment: Can you show the actual Car and Garage classes? The JSON doesn’t tell us which properties are mutable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added to post. It is just simple example to experiment. I know it does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun findDiff(current: Garage, updated: Garage): List<Car> {
    // preparing a map for fast search
    val currentCars = current.brands
        .flatMap { it.cars }    // list of all cars in "current" garage
        .associateBy { it.id }  // car.id -> car

    return updated.brands.asSequence()
        .flatMap { it.cars }                // list of all cars in "updated" garage
        .filter { it.id in currentCars }    // we remove cars that are not in the "current" garage
        .filter { it.name != currentCars.getValue(it.id).name } // filtering cars with the same id and different names
        .toList()
}
```

Comment: As this answer shows, many things that you'd have to do with a `for` (or `while`) loop in a traditional imperative language can be done more concisely — and more readably — in the functional style.  Of course, there are still some things that need an explicit loop; but before writing one in Kotlin, make sure there's not a better way!